# Looking to restrict duplicates but not delete

Tags: excel, vba

All!

I have some experience with JS and Python, but am relatively new to VBA. I have written a few successful scripts so far, including:

1) locate values in a column where I want all cells to be null, and once said cells have been located, delete the entire row(s) around them

2) locate nulls in a column where I need strings, and replaced said nulls with string

3) locate duplicates and remove them

now, what I am wanting to do, is a little like 3) but more complex. I want to search for duplicates in a column, and rather than deleting all duplicated and leaving one, I would like to write a script(s) that locates duplicates, and keeps 3, 5, 10 or 20 of the duplicate. Here is a simplified table of my problem:

```
+-----------+------------------------+--------+
|   Name    |         Email          | Animal |
+-----------+------------------------+--------+
| Lauretta  | Lauretta@barnyard.com  | Pig    |
| Irwin     | Irwin@barnyard.com     | Cat    |
| Leigh     | Leigh@barnyard.com     | Donkey |
| Eloy      | Eloy@barnyard.com      | Horse  |
| Elaina    | Elaina@barnyard.com    | Spider |
| Trinity   | Trinity@barnyard.com   | Pig    |
| Kanisha   | Kanisha@barnyard.com   | Pig    |
| Minna     | Minna@barnyard.com     | Spider |
| Shantelle | Shantelle@barnyard.com | Cat    |
| Renea     | Renea@barnyard.com     | Cat    |
| Catherina | Catherina@barnyard.com | Spider |
| Jamika    | Jamika@barnyard.com    | Horse  |
| Delphine  | Delphine@barnyard.com  | Pig    |
| Kristian  | Kristian@barnyard.com  | Horse  |
| Arlie     | Arlie@barnyard.com     | Spider |
| Katelynn  | Katelynn@barnyard.com  | Pig    |
| Philip    | Philip@barnyard.com    | Pig    |
| Antonette | Antonette@barnyard.com | Cat    |
| Ellamae   | Ellamae@barnyard.com   | Spider |
+-----------+------------------------+--------+
```

**Scenario**: I want to invite three of each animal, maximum, at random (random preferred but not a dealbreaker) to a soirée I am hosting.

**Problem**: How can I remove duplicates but leave **3** of each animal rather than just **1**? In my real life, there are thousands of animals in my contact database, not just twenty, and I also have bats, goats, rabbits etc. And I am also thinking about increasing my guestlist at some point in the future to invite 5, 10 or even 20 of each animal.

The desired finished product would look something like this (this would involve sorting, too - sorting also not a dealbreaker):

```
+-----------+------------------------+--------+
|   Name    |         Email          | Animal |
+-----------+------------------------+--------+
| Lauretta  | Lauretta@barnyard.com  | Pig    |
| Kanisha   | Kanisha@barnyard.com   | Pig    |
| Katelynn  | Katelynn@barnyard.com  | Pig    |
| Irwin     | Irwin@barnyard.com     | Cat    |
| Renea     | Renea@barnyard.com     | Cat    |
| Antonette | Antonette@barnyard.com | Cat    |
| Leigh     | Leigh@barnyard.com     | Donkey |
| Eloy      | Eloy@barnyard.com      | Horse  |
| Jamika    | Jamika@barnyard.com    | Horse  |
| Kristian  | Kristian@barnyard.com  | Horse  |
| Elaina    | Elaina@barnyard.com    | Spider |
| Catherina | Catherina@barnyard.com | Spider |
| Ellamae   | Ellamae@barnyard.com   | Spider |
+-----------+------------------------+--------+
```

Any help at all would be very much appreciated! :)

Comment: Do the animals ever change or will they be the same in all tests? You could just increment through the list deleting all after there are 3 of the same value?

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a free code-writing service, but exists to help others develop code or complex formulas. Suggest you read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIF to determine the number. Work from the botom up and delete every time the current number exceeds a static maximum.

```
with worksheets("sheet1")

    dim i as long mx as long

    mx = 5   'set the maximum number of any animal

    for i=.cells(.rows.count, "C").end(xlup).row to mx step -1
        if application.countif(.range("C:C"), .cells(i, "C")) > mx then
            .cells(i, "C").entirerow.delete
        end if
    next i

end with
```

Comment: this worked! You are amazing, thank you so much! I am learning every day. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA.

Add a helper column, perhaps named "Count"

```
D2:  =COUNTIF($C$2:C2,C2)
```

and fill down.

Then filter with Count `<=3`

You can sort the list also, to get all the animals together.